# whatsapp chat button with current url

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=601005108869&text={current webpage url}">whastsapp me now</a>
```

how to let the code
auto fill in {current webpage url}?

example,
visitor visit my site
current url >> http://sample.com/1-1

the code will be filled in as below

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=60105108869&text=http://sample.com/1-1">whastsapp me now</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.href` to get the current location and generate url text accordingly.

Lets say you have a button in your html:

```
<a id="whatsapp-button">Chat With Us</a>
```

In javascript file:

```js
// Get the element
$link = document.querySelector("#whatsapp-button");

// Generate url
$url = "api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=601005108869&text=" + window.location.href;

// Set url attribute of the link
$link.setAttribute('href', $url);
```

Make sure your javascript file runs after page load, which means either put it before the closing of body tag or use jQuery's `$( document ).ready()` method.

Comment: sorry im not a pro.   like this correct?                                      
                                                                                                                  < a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=601005108869&text= window.location.href ">whastsapp me now< /a >

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get the element
$link = document.querySelector("#whatsapp-button");

// Generate url
// "https://" add to above script now working fine
$url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=601005108869&text=" + window.location.href;

// Set url attribute of the link
$link.setAttribute('href', $url);
```

```html
 <a id="whatsapp-button">Chat With Us</a>
```

// Get the element
$link = document.querySelector("#whatsapp-button");

// Generate url
// "https://" add to above script now working fine
$url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=601005108869&text=" + window.location.href;

// Set url attribute of the link
$link.setAttribute('href', $url);